# no such file to load -- yet file is config.gem in environtment.rb file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, rubygems

I keep getting this error for different gems, the most recent is acts_as_reportable:

```
no such file to load -- acts_as_reportable
```

However, I have the following line in my environment.rb:

> config.gem 'acts_as_reportable'

And I also ran the following:

```
>gem install acts_as_reportable
```

It it output:

```
>gem install acts_as_reportable
Successfully installed acts_as_reportable-1.1.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for acts_as_reportable-1.1.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for acts_as_reportable-1.1.1...
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
config.gem 'acts_as_reportable', :lib => 'ruport/acts_as_reportable'
```

Found the correct require in the Ruport documentation [here](http://ruportbook.com/acts_as_reportable.html).  Explanation of the :lib option in the Rails API [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html#M002064).

Comment: hmm...even though acts_as_reportable is on github, it's not standalone, it needs to be a lib.  Hmm...wouldn't been nice if the ruport site explained that...let's check it out!

Comment: @Angela How about `config.gem 'acts_as_reportable', :lib => 'ruport/acts_as_reportable'`?

Comment: Hmm...didn't work, I had to remove it and then use a require 'ruport/acts_as_reportable" which is less than desirable....let me try again