# no such file to load -- rails (MissingSourceFile)... say what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm having an obnoxious and weird problem while trying to include the ThinkingTank gem into my rails project. When I include `gem 'thinkingtank'` in my project's Gemfile I get the following error:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require': no such file to load -- rails (MissingSourceFile)
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/thinkingtank-0.0.5/lib/thinkingtank.rb:1
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
 from ~/git/myproject/config/boot.rb:121:in `load_environment'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:137:in `process'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
 from ~/git/myproject/config/environment.rb:9
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:254:in `require'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:254:in `load_modules'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `each'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `load_modules'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:21:in `setup'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:54:in `start'
 from ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/irb:17
```

The output from `ruby -v` is:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-darwin10.6.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01
```

And the output from `rails -v` is:

```
Rails 2.3.5
```

I've followed the basic guidelines from [their documentation](https://indextank.com/documentation/thinkingtank) and from [similar SA questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050366/no-such-file-to-load-yet-file-is-config-gem-in-environtment-rb-file-in-rails). But none of issues have the rails gem going missing..

And yes, we are including rails in our Gemfile =)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try: require 'thinkingtank' in your gem file.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the comment although thinkingtank was already being required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving the the issue by just removing the 'require rails' statement. There were some other gem conflicts that caused problems but I was able to resolve them by making some small changes in the source. Thanks!